# TDS imperial items change

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Have the items that you get from the imperial levels in TDS changed?  When I collected them tonight I noticed they were different and cost more buxs to speed up the creation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the images did not change, nor did the quantities I already had assembled, but the descriptions certainly did!

Droid Works now produce Repair Droids instead of Astromech Droids. 
Officers Lounge now gives inspections instead of officers. Etc

The cost in bux to hurry production have now skyrocketed from 1 bux to 100 bux in the instance of my Sith Meditation Chamber. There is now a standard cost of 100 bux per hour to hurry an imperial item.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I noticed that too.  For instance, I swore the Sith meditation chamber used to make "Mind Tricks", and now it makes "Sith drones".  I previously noticed that the bux required to speed up building varied wildly from floor to floor.  I'd have my superlaser level wanting only 5 bux to sped up 5 hours of work, while other floors requiring only an hour of work required 84 bux!